# How to use Jenkins to handle HTTP Request?

Tags: http, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I'm new to Jenkins and I don't know if with it I can do what I want. I need to send a file from one point (in another PC) to an endpoint in a server where Jenkins exist, I believe the best way to send the file is with a POST Request because I can send metadata that could help me to process the file. The thing is I don't know if I can configure this endpoint with Jenkins so it could recieve the file or I have to use another thing to create this endpoint and later it should call Jenkins. I don't know if a Jenkins' Plugin could help me here or something.

What I was considering was maybe using Kafka to handle the requests (I believe it can do that) with a queue and it later could call Jenkins to execute the actions I really want with the file that arrived and the details that came in the metadata.

BTW, I'm using Ubuntu 20, but this should be able to run in Windows too, but for now I only want to test this in Ubuntu.

Also, if anyone could recomend me some software that is like Jenkins only to see other options. The main feature that I found in Jenkins that I want to use for now besides what I'm asking in  this post is the capability of process the emails that arrives in an specific mail, this is done with a Plugin, the CI/CD features are welcome, tho, I haven't use them yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need HTTP requests (Jenkins shouldn't start an HTTP server as part of your pipeline)... You could upload the file to object storage (like S3), then check its existence and download it whenever (Kafka is not meant to be used for file-transfer)

Comment: Thanks, I will takes this in consideration